# Cannot access $scope variable with angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a code piece of this:

```
$scope.getPlaylists = function() {
    Restangular.all('getPlaylists').getList().then(function(getPlaylists){
          var plist;
              console.log("getplists: "+getPlaylists);
          for(var i=0; i < getPlaylists[0].length; i++) {
              plist = getPlaylists[0][i];
              $scope.playlists.push(plist);
              console.log("inside loop: "+$scope.playlists.length);
          }
              console.log("loop end: "+$scope.playlists.length);
          });
    console.log("total length: "+$scope.playlists.length);
};
```

Inside and just after the loop, I can see the length of the playlists in the console, but `total length:` is seen zero. What should I do so that I can access the `$scope.playlists.length` with the correct value?

Comment: `getPlaylist()` is a member of `$scope`, so you access the class with `this`

Comment: getList() is an async call, "total length" gets logged before "loop end". use callback.

Comment: @Nish How do I use a callback there?

Answer (score 0):

You're logging the values after an *async* call (`getList`) - put the log statement within the callback or pass your data to a callback function and do the work there.

```
Restangular.all('getPlaylists').getList().then(function(getPlaylists){
    //all work pertaining to the info received has to be done here
    //Or an external callback function    
});
//Code here does not know about received data from the async call - it's still in progress
```

Comment: How can I use an external callback?